# How to get period and at symbol to work in regex. How to get quantifiers to work?

Tags: regex

I am learning HTML and one of the things covered is Regex. The problematic part of my assignment is that I must match exactly one period, and one @. The problem I am having is the movement I add a second symbol, it stop working entirely. It will work with just a period, or just an @, but I try to use those two, it will not work. I am using Regex 101, but other regex testers do not work with the expression I have designed. Furthermore, even if I drop the period, the quantifier for the @ doesn't work or at least it doesn't work like I would expect.

Expression: /\w[A-Z0-9a-z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[@]{1}/gm

Test String: JasonP.w@
JasonP.w@@@ (This one shouldn't work because there is more than one @)

How do I solve this?

Comment: what should be your desired result?

Comment: I want a regex that matches a set of requirements so that it returns true for a email checker. In order for the string to be valid I must have exactly one period, and one @.

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the strings in the order of first a dot and then an @ you can use [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^.@]` matching any char except a `.` and except an `@`

To prevent matching across newlines, you could use `[^.@\r\n]`

```
^[^.@]*\.[^.@]*@[^.@]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DIb1wt/1)

To match both ways, you can use an alternation `|`:

```php
^(?:[^.@]*\.[^.@]*@[^.@]*|[^.@]*@[^.@]*.[^.@]*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ExePZP/1)